# Is there a way to resolve nested interfaces on DTOs in a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

We are having an issue with the Razor view engine not resolving nested interfaces. Sample code:

```
public interface IDto
{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public interface IUserDto: IDto
{
  string Username {get;set;}
}

//The view
@model IUserDto

//pukes on this line
@Html.DisplayFor(u => u.Id)
```

Should we be using concrete models on our views? Is the Razor view engine not capable of using multiple interfaces per model?

Answer (score 2):

This was a change in ASP.NET MVC 3 that [I already brought to the attention](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636341/modelmetadata-fromlambdaexpression-has-changed-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rtm) of Microsoft (this scenario worked on ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2).

Here's their official answer:

> Hi Darin (and others),
>
> This was a deliberate change that we introduced to ASP.NET MVC 3 that
>   was the result of a trade-off between having better support for
>   inherited models or better support for models that implement
>   interfaces. We ended up favoring inherited models, which from our
>   experience is a more common approach.
>
> The fundamental problem is that when an interface is implemented by a
>   class that the class doesn't *really* inherit any of the members of
>   the interface. The key here is that because it doesn't inherit the
>   members of the interface, it also does not inherit the metadata on
>   those members.
>
> Thanks, The ASP.NET Team

Now to the point

> Should we be using concrete models on our views?

Not necessary. You could still use interfaces on your main views, but then have editor/display templates with concrete types. At runtime based on the actual type of the view model the framework will pick the correct template where you will have the concrete type and it will resolve the Id property.

Another possibility is to use abstract classes instead of interfaces (beurk I know :-) typically Microsoftish)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? Are you talking about custom templates?

Comment: @DDiVita, yes I am talking about custom editor/display templates.

Comment: That stinks about interfaces...While I get what they are saying, I am not sure I agree with it.

Comment: @DDiVita, me neither, that's why I issued this bug report.